# PHP Using sessions to save two variables across project files

Tags: php, session, parse-platform

I am a little rusty on PHP. What I would like to do is save 2 variables to be used across my project. I would like to save the email and the password from my login page to be used later on to Parse my database on Parse.com.

Using reference link: [http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php]

---

SOLVED, thank you @Fred -ii- for your help and explanations!

Login file:

```
try{

$query = new ParseQuery("Clients");
$query->equalTo("email", "$email");
$query->equalTo("password","$password");
$results = $query->find();

} catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();

}
if(count($results)==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
 header("Location: http://localhost/ClientPortal/mainMenu.php");
}
```

mainMenu file:

```
   session_start();
   $email = $_SESSION['email'];
   $password = $_SESSION['password']; //* fixed spelling error (used to be 'passowrd')
   session_commit();

try{

   $query = new ParseQuery("Clients");
   $query->equalTo("email", "$email");
   $query->equalTo("password","$password");
   $results = $query->find();

   } catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();

   }

if(count($results)==1){
echo "<p align=center>1 correct row</p>";
}
else{
 echo "<p align=center>NO correct rows</p>";
}
```

Comment: Typo `$_SESSION['passowrd']`? If not, do `$_SESSION['password']`

Comment: Sidenote: If you want valid HTML, change `<p align=center>` to `<p align=\"center\">`

Comment: You are amazing!!! But I have an additional question for you, it is running pretty slow. Can I use session_close() after I use my sessions so that it works faster?

Comment: You're welcome. That's what years of being a (*past*) text editor for a publishing house paid off ;)

Comment: To answer your second question question; yes I imagine it would. However it's [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) and not [`session_close()`](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=function.session_close&lang=en&scope=404quickref) if that's the actual function you were wanting to use, [doesn't exist](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=function.session_close&lang=en&scope=404quickref).

Comment: @Fred-ii- , out of interest: can you exlpain why that would speed up? I always thought that sessions are closed automatically at the end of the request. That it only matters if you have two browser windows open loading at the same time (session-locking).

Comment: @Fred Only necessary if you want valid *X*HTML - SGML-based versions (including HTML 4.0 I believe) are fine with unquoted attributes, as is HTML5. (With some restrictions, naturally, but none violated here.)

Comment: Makes sense, I got that confused with SessionHandlerInterface::close — Close the session. Thank you!

Comment: @PetervanderWal [`This could help`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php#102685) shed some light on the subject.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm just "Old School"; it's by personal preference. I like tags to render as `<p align="center">` rather than `<p align=center>` which could pose issues for older browsers. Things like forms could pose a problem when it comes to named form elements. `name=email` as opposed to `name="email"`.

Comment: @Fred Sure, definitely better style to always quote, just nit-picking your mention of "valid HTML" :)

Comment: @IMSoP *Ah* yes; I should have used another word instead of "valid". I stand corrected.

Comment: @MadsterMaddness I take it as problem solved?

Comment: @MadsterMaddness You're welcome. However, it's best not to edit the problematic code to the working one, because future readers may visit this question and ask themselves "why the question, there's nothing wrong with this". You can either re-edit, do a rollback, delete the question or I can put in an answer to close the question and be marked as solved if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Fred -ii- for helping me solve this!!!

Login file:

```
try{

$query = new ParseQuery("Clients");
$query->equalTo("email", "$email");
$query->equalTo("password","$password");
$results = $query->find();

} catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();

}
if(count($results)==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
 header("Location: http://localhost/ClientPortal/mainMenu.php");
}
```

mainMenu file:

```
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password']; //* fixed spelling error (used to be 'passowrd')
session_commit();

try{

  $query = new ParseQuery("Clients");
  $query->equalTo("email", "$email");
 $query->equalTo("password","$password");
 $results = $query->find();

 } catch(Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();

 }

if(count($results)==1){
echo "<p align=center>1 correct row</p>";
 }
 else{
 echo "<p align=center>NO correct rows</p>";
}
```

Comment: It's no biggie really. Don't get me wrong, I'm not in this for the points, although they do help in regards to reputation. I posted [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189671/php-using-sessions-to-save-two-variables-across-project-files#comment39226644_25189671) but didn't get an answer. People might get the wrong impression if/when they visit the question. There are some out there who take Stack just a wee-bit too serious for my taste. ;)

Comment: I feel the same way. I am just trying to learn. I made sure to put your name above the answer so you get credit for your help.

Comment: Yes I saw that, thanks and I was glad to help. Yet as I said also; if it's been solved, you shouldn't edit your question's code with the corrected one. I appreciate the mention, and glad that the matter got resolved, *cheers* - Enjoy coding :) - I +1 btw.